# How can I prevent macports from taking over my PATH?

Tags: macos, unix, path, macports

How can I prevent macports from taking over my `PATH`? I still want to have the installed software show up, but I want things in the standard system paths (`/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, ...) to have precedence over anything that macports installs.

Answer (score 8):

MacPorts Installer automatically modifies the environment so that MacPorts commands are called before system commands in its [Postflight Script](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell.postflight). You can type **env** in the terminal to see what your PATH is currently. If your **~/.profile** was modified, you can manually change it back from:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

You must restart the terminal for this to take effect.

If this isn't the problem, check the **environment.plist** with the **Property List Editor**:

```
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

Comment: My ~/.profle was modified by macports, there was even a comment in there telling me so. I commented out the PATH append in there and now my PATH is back to how it used to be. I'm on OSX 10.8 if it helps anyone. Thanks again hanleyp.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have  line in your .bashrc or .profile that sources `/opt/local/share/macports/setupenv.bash`

You will have to remove that and setup your PATH (and MAN_PATH) yourself.  You can use the macports file as a guide, just switch

`export PATH="${binpath}${sbinpath}${PATH}"`

to

export PATH="${PATH}${binpath}${sbinpath}"

Comment: i don't have a Mac so maybe it's different, but don't you need separators between the variables in your export statements?  eg "export PATH=${PATH}**:**${binpath}**:**${sbinpath}"

Comment: asterisks for emphasizing the colons, naturally...

Comment: Yes, you do.  This is part of a larger script that adds the necessary colons to `${binpath}` and `${sbinpath}`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked, but for the benefit of everyone else who finds this page:

On my system, Macports modified `~/.bash_login` to insert its insidious `$PATH` modification command.

Comment: `/.zprofile` nowadays